# Deploy to openshift - wtf.TextArea

Tags: flask, openshift, flask-wtforms

I would like to deploy my application in Flask to OpenShift but I got error message

```
[Sun Feb 09 06:51:50 2014] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]     class CKTextAreaWidget(wtf.TextArea):
[Sun Feb 09 06:51:50 2014] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TextArea'
```

Do you know what should be included in install_requires section in setup.py? I included 'wtforms' and 'Flask-wtf'

Thank you

Piece of code is:

```
from flask.ext import admin, wtf

class CKTextAreaWidget(wtf.TextArea):
    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('class_', 'ckeditor')
        return super(CKTextAreaWidget, self).__call__(field, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Does this run locally?  The error should also show up when you run your application locally, and it will be a bit easier to debug there.  As it is, it looks like you are doing something like this `import flask.ext.wtforms as wtf` - in which case, the error message is telling you the issue - `TextArea` is not exposed on `wtforms` and you'll need to import it explicitly from `wtforms.fields`.

Comment: yes, it runs locally.

Comment: Are you sure your local version of WTForms and flask-wtforms is the same as the deployed version?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your setup.py you should have something that looks like this

install_requires=['Flask', 'WTForms'],

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Flask-WTF version 0.9.4. Switching back to Flask-WTF version 0.8 fixed the issue.

I would imagine it has to do with this ([from the docs](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/upgrade.html)):
[image]